# material-ui tabs Component Height

Tags: material-ui

I use Swipeable tabs and find that its `height` can scroll and I do not know where to change its height to be auto. Instead, I just want to remove it.

```
 <SwipeableViews  index={this.state.slideIndex} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange}>
     <div style={tabsStyles.height}>
          <h2 style={tabsStyles.headline}>Tabs with sadsada dasda</h2>
               Swipe to see the next slide.<br />
     </div>
</SwipeableViews>
```

Comment: have you tried by passing style directly like this `<SwipeableViews  style={....}>` or using attribute `tabItemContainerStyle` ?